# Qt what happens to QGraphicsItems when added to QGraphicsLinearLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a vector of pointers to QGraphicsItems, which have all been added to a QGraphicsLinearLayout.

I'm worried about memory management.

1) What happens when I add them?
Do they get parented automatically or do I need to explicitly call item.setParentLayoutItem(layout)?

2) If they are parented does Qt handle their deletions? (when the parent gets deleted)

3) I also have a remove method that removes the item from my vector and the layout. Should I remove the item from the layout before deleting it/calling vector.erase(...)... or does this depend on whether I parented or not?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What happens when I add them? Do they get parented automatically or
>   do I need to explicitly call item.setParentLayoutItem(layout)?

From qt documentation:

> If the item inherits both QGraphicsItem and QGraphicsLayoutItem (such
>   as QGraphicsWidget does) the item is really part of two ownership
>   hierarchies. This property informs what the layout should do with its
>   child items when it is destructed. In the case of QGraphicsWidget, it
>   is preferred that when the layout is deleted it won't delete its
>   children (since they are also part of the graphics item hierarchy).

see [ownedByLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicslayoutitem.html#ownedByLayout) and [setOwnedByLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicslayoutitem.html#setOwnedByLayout)

Theoretically they are, but you can parameterize the deletion with the documentation provided by the two links above.

> 2) If they are parented does Qt handle their deletions?

Yes

> 3) I also have a remove method that removes the item from my vector
>   and the layout. Should I remove the item from the layout before
>   deleting it/calling vector.erase(...)... or does this depend on
>   whether I parented or not?

If your `QGraphicsLayoutItem` owns (parent/child relation) all your `QGraphicsItem`, they will all be deleted when the parent is deleted.

If you want to remove a single element, then a simple call to:

```
theItemYouWantToDelete->deleteLater()
```

should suffice.